# how to launch Chrome using remote webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, c#

I have set up 2 PCs as selenium hub & node.Now, I am trying to browse a URL in that node, from a console app that runs in the hub. But there is an error when initialising the browser.Both PCs run on windows 7.

```
//setting up the hub
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role hub");

//setting up the node
string Command1 = "/C cmdkey.exe /add:\\DES100 /user:abcd /pass:abcd123";
string Command2 = "psexec.exe \\DES100 -w D:\\Selenium java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role node -hub http://hubip:4444/grid/register";
Process.Start("cmd.exe", string.Format("{0} && {1}", Command1, Command2));

//open the browser

//ERROR AT BELOW LINE
IWebDriver NewDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://100.100.10.100:4444/wd/hub"), 
                                DesiredCapabilities.Chrome(),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

> ERROR The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://100.100.10.100:4444/wd/hub/session timed out after 180 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) mentions this remedy for this error :

> If you are using the RemoteWebDriver and you get the The path to the chromedriver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property error message you likely need to check that one of these conditions is met:
>
> The chromedriver binary is in the system path, or
>
> The Selenium Server was started with -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\path\to\your\chromedriver.exe

Check if you are not missing any of these.

Comment: I have followed that remedy & there is a new error. Not sure if relates to selenium or other. Please look at the edited  question & error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322596/selenium-error-the-http-request-to-the-remote-webdriver-timed-out-after-60-sec

Comment: I have increased the time as you see. No change

Comment: This is not an issue due to time. It looks a difficult issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role hub");
```

You didn't specify any port for the hub. Then the default hub -port is port 4444. I'm wondering why you were trying to connect "http://100.100.10.100:5555/wd/hub" instead of "http://100.100.10.100:4444/wd/hub" ?